# Horizontal jQuery Slider and Lightbox2 into One HTML5 Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, lightbox2

I am currently trying to create a portfolio website and I have my work scrolling horizontally left to right. I added Lightbox2 so once you click on each piece of work, it enlarges which works great! I need to customize my horizontal scrolling. I need to have an arrow on either side so you can scroll through the thumbs of my work.

The problem comes into play, I'm a beginner to JQuery and I looked up a separate template to do this but the second one never works! Any help would be amazing. I love StackOverflow!

jsfiddle.net/uPLQR/1

I tried to add this to it:
http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/index.html

If anyone has any other way of adding arrow buttons I can scroll with that would be unreal!

Comment: any piece of code? the `div` containing the thumbs need a declared `width` + `overflow:scroll` or `overflow:auto`

Comment: I will add code now, the scroll works fine i can't add the second bit of JQuery.

Comment: I have added code above :)

Comment: oops correct css:
    #projectcontent {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 5%;
 padding-top: 0;
 width: 80%;
 height: 100%;
 overflow: scroll;
 white-space: nowrap;
 margin-left: 10%; }

Comment: so...have you started the div scroll or just included its javascript?

Comment: i really dont understand what i need to do ive dropped in everything from that link but its not doing anything

Comment: post whole page code here http://jsfiddle.net save and put generated link in question, please

Comment: i really like this one too thinking it would be easier: http://als.musings.it/#demo but i can't get it to work

#demo2

Comment: jsfiddle... can you upload your images there?http://jsfiddle.net/uPLQR/1/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/uPLQR/2/embedded/result/

Comment: First of all check this manual http://smoothdivscroll.com/dependencies.html which says everything this plugin needs to work, make sure all files are added correctly (and in the same order), you have jquery added already so skip it, http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/index.html#quickdemo try using the code changing `#makeMeScrollable` to your div `#projectcontent` if you have further problems update the fiddle and post back, and no you can't put images there unless you give the full address